# What are basic methodologies on solving questions related to comparison of rate of growth of two different functions?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

How to compare rate of growth for following functions?

In other words, is $f(n)$ = $O( \, g(n) \, )$ or $g(n)$ = $O(\, f(n) \, )$?

$f(n) = n^{\frac{4}{3}}$  and $g(n) = n*(\log(n))^3$

How to solve these kind of questions in general (Basic methodologies on how to approach these questions) ? Are limits always bound to give right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), $$f=O(g) \iff  \frac{|f|}{|g|} \text {is bounded}$$

In your case, this translates to considering $$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{4/3}}{n(\log n)^3} = \lim _{n \to \infty} \frac {n^{1/3}} {(\log n)^3}$$

Now use [L'Hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) three times:

\begin{align} 
\lim \frac {n^{1/3}} {(\log n)^3} & = \lim \frac{\frac{1}{3}n^{-2/3}} {3 (\log n)^2  (1/n)} \\ & = \lim \frac{n^{1/3}} {9 (\log n)^2} \\ &= \lim \frac{\frac{1}{3}n^{-2/3}}{18 (\log n) (1/n)} \\ &= \lim \frac{n^{1/3}}{54 \log n} \\ &= \lim \frac{\frac{1}{3}n^{-2/3}}{54 (1 / n)} \\ &= \frac{n^{1/3}}{162}
\end{align}

which is clearly unbounded i.e. $f$ is not in $O(g)$.

Performing the converse analysis however, we find that $\lim _{n \to \infty} g/f = 0$, and therefore $g = O(f)$.